# How do I find the derivative of the function $f(u)=5\sqrt{u}$

Tags: derivatives, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

### Find the derivative of $f(u)=5\sqrt{u}$.

This just drives me crazy. I am able to solve this problem with some hand-waving, in this case - standard methods like power rules and so on. Piece of cake. Problem is, I want to solve this equation with non-standard analysis methods, and I only get so far before I become totally bogged down in a marsh.

I have come this far before I don't know what to do (and I'm using Jerome H. Keisler's [methods](https://www.math.wisc.edu/formMail/throttle.php?URL=/~keisler/chapter_1b.pdf) (see page 22) of calculating derivatives):

$$\Delta y=5\sqrt{u+\Delta u}-5\sqrt{u}.$$

It's probably some rule that I'm not familiar with, or some trick you could use - or something entirely else.

**Please do not answer this question using conventional methods, like the concept of limits.** For example, use the standard part function instead of limits.

The correct answer is $y'=\frac{5}{2\sqrt{u}}$.

Appreciated,

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: @Neutronic Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $u>0$. By the conjugate expression one gets, as $\Delta u \to 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta y=5\sqrt{u+\Delta u}-5\sqrt{u}&=5\cdot\frac{(\sqrt{u+\Delta u}-\sqrt{u})(\sqrt{u+\Delta u}+\sqrt{u})}{(\sqrt{u+\Delta u}+\sqrt{u})}
\\&=5\cdot\frac{\Delta u}{\sqrt{u+\Delta u}+\sqrt{u}}.
\end{align}
$$ Then, as $\Delta u \to 0$, one has
$$
\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u}=5\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{u+\Delta u}+\sqrt{u}} \to \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{u}}.
$$

Comment: How did you arrive at the last step?

Comment: I've used $\sqrt{u+\Delta u} \to \sqrt{u+0}$ since $\Delta u \to 0$ giving $\sqrt{u+\Delta u}+\sqrt{u} \to \sqrt{u+0}+\sqrt{u}=2\sqrt{u}$.

Comment: You write that $\frac{\Delta y}{\color{green} {\Delta u}}. But, if you divide $\Delta y$ with $\Delta u$, shouldn't both sides be divided by $\Delta u$ or how should I look at it?

Comment: Since $\Delta y=5\cdot\frac{\Delta u}{\sqrt{u+\Delta u}+\sqrt{u}}$ then $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u}=5\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{u+\Delta u}+\sqrt{u}}$ isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Amateur learner of math so far ;p

Comment: @AndreasAlmgren No problem, you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about how to prove this using non-standard analysis but I think I know a good way to start, with a standard trick to deal with the difference of square roots (leaving out the $5$):
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta y  & =   (\sqrt{u + \Delta u} - \sqrt{u}) \times
\frac{  \sqrt{u + \Delta u} + \sqrt{u}  }{  \sqrt{u + \Delta u} + \sqrt{u}} \\
& = \frac{u + \Delta u - u}{\sqrt{u + \Delta u} + \sqrt{u}}  \\
& = \frac{  \Delta u }{\sqrt{u + \Delta u} + \sqrt{u}}  
\end{align} .
$$

Can you finish now with a standard non-standard argument?